# how to see all the tables that are on my android device ?

Tags: android, android-database

I looking for some app that can show me all the databases that are define on my android device.

Actually, I looking for two kind of application

1. that i can setup on my android device - and to see the database that are on my android device
2. that i can see the database from my develop software ( android studio )

Answer (score 3):

Check this app link .I think this will help you.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.andsen.asqlitemanager&hl=en

Comment: after downloading from play store, just click on OPEN DATABASE -> click on the folder inside this you will get your database which you created for your android application.